# C++ beginner String pointer in visual studio

Tags: .net, c++-cli

Referring to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815657 there in the code they write

```
String *sURL = S"http://www.microsoft.com";
```

I assume this defines a pointer and not a normal object compared to

```
String sURL
```

Correct? But what is the "S" before the actual string?

Visual Studio tells me that this line of code is wrong, it is saying

> an ordinary pointer to a C++/CLI ref class or Interface class is not
>   allowed

What do they mean with that? I use visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Using ^ instead of *?

Comment: @Macmade Your comment is cryptic...

Comment: @piwi Different pointer syntax for .NET objects...

Comment: The KB article is old and not being maintained.  The syntax it uses is for Managed C++, a different animal from C++/CLI.  You'd have to use the /clr:oldSyntax option to get that statement to compile.  Don't use it, it is old and no longer supported in VS2015.  Use the [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-2) for WebRequest instead.

Answer (score 1):

First thing, this is not plain c++. It is C++/CLI (C++ modified for Common Language Infrastructure) which is a language specification created by Microsoft and intended to supersede Managed Extensions for C++.

So, when you have a pointer in a normal statement like the one mentioned above, you got to change the syntax in CLI

```
String ^sURL = S"http://www.microsoft.com";
```

And the `S`you used in front of the actual string is present there for `typecast` the `std::string` to the `System::String`

Comment: okay, thanks. I don't want to do much, only sending some GET requests (maybe a POST) and parse the result. Do I Need this MS specification or do I have a Chance to stay with the plain C++?

Comment: @AndyAndroid: Considering that there are web browsers on Mac and Linux, you can figure that out yourself ;) But here's a tip: `libcurl`.

Comment: Not quite - the `S` says the string literal that follows should be typed as `System::String^` instead of `const char*`